VSCodium not loading plugins/can't connect to live server
I'm having trouble with VSCodium, as it's not loading plugins at all, and I'm unable to connect to the live server also. When I search for plugins, all I get is Error while fetching extensions. Failed to fetch. Everything was working up until a few days ago. I installed a firewall app, but then deleted it when all of this happened. I'm not sure how to fix any of this. When I searched how to fix the error, it said to edit the settings.json file, but I am not that tech-savvy yet. Any help is appreciated!
I changed firewall settings, I uninsstalled and re-installed both VSCodium and Visual Studio Code. No luck however.
